# regexp on finding elements in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html-parsing

How can i "find" all elements with those id:

> ctl00_cphContent_ctl05_Panel01,
>
> ctl00_cphContent_ctl06_Panel01,
>
> ctl00_cphContent_ctl07_Panel01,
>
> ctl00_cphContent_ctl08_Panel01,
> etc...

I tried

```
foreach($html->find('a#ctl00_cphContent_ctl'.*.'_Panel01') as $positions) { echo "Test!";}
```

But it doesn't work! Can someone help me please? I search but didn't find something similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the simple HTML DOM parses documentation http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find, I don't think that it includes full regex functionality. However it does seem to have basic matching. Try this:

```
$html->find( '[id^=ctl00_cphContent_ctl]' )
```

Obviously this wont just match id tags like ctl00_cphContent_ctl05_Panel01, but will also match things like ctl00_cphContent_ctrandomstuffhere. But it doesn't appear to be possible to do a full regexp match in the way you want.