# How to find all the images with jpg extension with DOM?

Tags: php, regex, dom

I want to find all the images with DOM

```
*.jpg || *.jpeg || *.gif
```

i can't use this

```
$content = // my php content
$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
$html_base->load($content);
foreach($html_base->find('img') as $element)
```

Because all images are not found im 'img' tag

I read [Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) and  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429755/regexp-on-finding-elements-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser) and i tried

```
foreach($html_base->find('[*.img]') as $element)
```

but it doesn't find the images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regexp on finding elements in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429755/regexp-on-finding-elements-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

Comment: where can images be found on your page ? in text ? in tag attributes ?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ something like that </style></head><body style="background:url('http://www.example.fr/drive/background_Bio_sb.jpg')

Comment: you will not be able to use only one query for all images (at least using the dom parser) use this `$html_base->find('[style*=.jpg]')` => get all elements having `.jpg` in the style tag

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ thanks but it shows nothing